# Posted form data remains in memory

Tags: php, session-cookies, postdata

My modal has a simple form in it and the form post data to `process.php` page. The `$_POST['message']` and other posted data will be process inside `process.php`, however the value of `$_POST['message']` and other posted data's values remains on the page. Means, when I `echo $_POST['message']` inside `process.php` and refresh the page, the value keeps showing up! 
in which the `process.php` runs its things again and I don't want that!
I am not sure where the session comes from or this cause by cookie but I don't want that. I want that the posted data will be removed after processing inside `process.php` page.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume the refresh you are doing is resubmitting the form data - your browser is likely warning you of this when you refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force to unset it ,
unset(var) OR unset($_POST['message'])